# Symfony PDO exception could not find driver

Tags: php, database, symfony, database-connection

I know this question has already been asked but I could not find an answer that works for me.

I am on Linux and I created a symfony 4 project with composer, and I wanted to install EasyBundle admin.

Everything is working good, but when I make `php bin/console server:run` and go to the address link, and put `/admin` at the end to go to the page, I have an error:

> "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver")."

I searched all day, I tried everything but I can't make it work.

Comment: it seems your database is not configured

Comment: i don't know, i am not a professional AT ALL in configuration server web etc..

Comment: i think i don't have a database, or if i have one, i don't know where and how configure it

Answer (score 1):

Install mysql. Then do

```
bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

Then

```
bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Comment: I saw this erlier, and i tried, when i make sudo yum install php-mysql, it says : Last metadata expiration check: 1:39:24 ago on Thu 07 Feb 2019 04:02:55 PM CET.
No match for argument: php-mysql
Error: Unable to find a match
And when i want to create a database whith symfony, same problem, could not find pdo driver

Answer (score 0):

The **First** thing before starting your web app is to setup an appropriate environment.

In your case you need to setup a LAMP or LEMP stack.

Depending on your linux distribution there can be different manipulation. The details of such manipulations are out the scope of this question.

Comment: I know that but i don't know what i have to do to have an appropriate environnement

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you should do in order to run your newly established Symfony project.

First you have to set up a database management system on your machine. Although the others have suggested MySQL, I'd advise to start with sqlite3. The setup is much easier and it's great for development purposes.

Install `sqlite3` on your machine. If you have a debian-based distribution you could do it with:

```
sudo apt install sqlite3 php-sqlite3
```

or using the package manager.

After the successful installation you have to modify two files:

**`.env`**

Find the following line:

```
# DATABASE_URL=mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name
```

If it is not commented, comment it and add the following line below:

```
DATABASE_URL="sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/app.db"
```

**`config/packages/doctrine.yaml`**

This file should look like this:

```
parameters:
    # Adds a fallback DATABASE_URL if the env var is not set.
    # This allows you to run cache:warmup even if your
    # environment variables are not available yet.
    # You should not need to change this value.
    env(DATABASE_URL): ''

doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_sqlite'
        server_version: '3'
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
        types:
            json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

The most important part is `doctrine.dbal`. The section `doctrine.orm` might eventually differ in your project. Essential is to set the `driver: 'pdo_sqlite'` and `server_version: '3'`.

Now you can follow the answer of @goto and your database should be created.

On the command line you can check that with:

```
sqlite3 var/app.db
```

Issue the command `.tables` and the tables should be listed.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue on Windows with XAMPP because in .env I added the wrong port of MySQL, instead of:

*DATABASE_URL="mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name?serverVersion=5.7"*

I wrote:
*DATABASE_URL="mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3366/db_name?serverVersion=5.7"*

When I corrected it to:
*DATABASE_URL="mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name?serverVersion=5.7"*

I was able to run:
*php bin/console doctrine:database:create*

I hope it can help people that made the same mistake.